# Restore the old Firefox Design

Tags: firefox

I just realized that Firefox updated its design and now looks completely ugly (like Chrome)

How can I restore the old Design? Especially the design from the menu and the URL bar. If I want a Browser that looks like Chrome, I would take Chrome.

Comment: If you stick to version 56.0 it is possible using [Classic Them Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/). This no longer works in 57.0

Comment: Prior to V57, you could use the Stylish add-on to customize appearance (selecting from a huge library of customizations or writing your own).  The library included styles and themes from various versions.  That add-on has been reworked for compatibility with V57+, now called [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html).  I haven't tested the new version yet because I've been avoiding V57 due to reliance on some legacy add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

You can't restore it completely. The previous menu is gone for good.

To remove the extra space around the URL address, right-click on the empty space, choose "Customize" and drag-and-drop the flexible spaces to the inventory that will appear. While in the customize mode, you can pick another theme on the bottom of the page to see if it pleases you.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to switch to one of the other browsers forked from Firefox that are maintaining old extensions - [Waterfox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfox) is one of them, [Pale Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Moon_(web_browser)) is another, there may very well be more.

Answer (score 0):

[image: before Firefox 57 and after]

well I was able to recreate my docked Firefox customization

the point is not the maybe vintage design but the app I created to apply again complete themes

anyway I already added new modern styles to the collection see more here https://byfrankell.webnode.com/